# Progress element does not respect right margin

Tags: html, css

I was trying to stylize the `<progress>` HTML element, using a few tricks I picked up online, but I came accross a problem. My CSS should, in theory, set the `margin-right` and `margin-left` properties to `10px` based on `margin: 2px 10px;`. However, that is not the case. The `<progress>` element, which I am trying to style, respects the `margin-left`, but does not respect the `margin-right`. Any suggestions?

#### Code

```css
progress {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin: 2px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0.5px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background: #eeeeee;
  color: #01579b;
}
/* Foreground - webkit browsers */
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #01579b;
  border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
}
/* Background - webkit browsers */
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: #eeeeee;
}
/* Foreground - Firefox */
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: #01579b;
  border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
}
/* Max value - webkit browsers */
progress[value="1000"]::-webkit-progress-value {
  border-radius: 1px;
}
/* Max value - Firefox */
progress[value="1000"]::-moz-progress-bar {
  border-radius: 1px;
}
```

```html
<progress value="450" max="1000"></progress>
```

You can also check out [the relative Codepen](http://codepen.io/chalarangelo/pen/dORdgV?editors=1100) I prepared.

#### Notes

1. Changing the `margin` shorthand to individual properties did not make any difference.
2. Some parts of the CSS stylesheet might be a little bit irrelevant (possibly stuff like the browser-specific styling) or maybe not. I do not exactly know what is causing this problem.
3. Tested this on Firefox 50 and Chrome 54, same problem in both. I can reproduce the issue both locally and using Codepen and the provided snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're wrong: it *is* respecting `margin-right`. If you use your browser's console/developer tools to inspect the progress bar, you'll see that it does indeed have a `margin-right` of `10px`.

The problem is with `width: 100%`. A `width` set to a percentage means ["a  of containing block's width"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width). You're then *adding* to that width the margin. So the box that contains your progress bar will be `20px` bigger than the containing element would have been, so it will overflow.

Abandon `width: 100%`: it's rarely necessary. What you want here is `width: auto`, which for all `block` elements means "take up as much space as you can within the containing element" and which automatically adjusts for `margin`.

```css
progress {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  height: 14px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin: 2px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0.5px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background: #eeeeee;
  color: #01579b;
}
/* Foreground - webkit browsers */
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #01579b;
  border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
}
/* Background - webkit browsers */
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: #eeeeee;
}
/* Foreground - Firefox */
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: #01579b;
  border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
}
/* Max value - webkit browsers */
progress[value="1000"]::-webkit-progress-value {
  border-radius: 1px;
}
/* Max value - Firefox */
progress[value="1000"]::-moz-progress-bar {
  border-radius: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; margin: 0px 50px;">
  <progress value="450" max="1000"></progress>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, I now understand the problem and why my margin "did not work" while in reality it did. However, I want to keep my element's width to take up as much space as possible and auto will shrink the progress bar. Is there any way to work around this? `width: auto` is not the way to go for me.

Comment: @AngelosChalaris It does take up as much space as possible. It doesn't shrink it. The only reason it doesn't take up the whole space is the `margin` values on (a) the `progress` element and (b) the surrounding `div`.

Comment: Yes, but I want the margin to be on the element itself, not a surrounding `<div>` if possible and I would like to have the element fill the whole line except `10px` on each side. Is that possible without a wrapper?

Comment: @AngelosChalaris Just remove the `margin: 0px 50px` from the HTML then.

Comment: What you suggested does not make any difference. Look at this codepen: http://codepen.io/chalarangelo/pen/qqjoOp?editors=1100

Comment: @AngelosChalaris But it's doing exactly what you say. It's filling the containing box with a margin of `10px` to the left and right. What else do you want?

Comment: Ok, let me explain it clearly: The sample I originally provided, if not provided with a `margin-right` and `margin-left` would fill a whole line (`100%` of its `width`), however adding the `margin` made the `width` = `100% + 20px`. What I want is for the width to be `100%` wihout the extra `20px` added from the `margin` - aka behave like this: http://codepen.io/chalarangelo/pen/JbJLYO but instead of the `auto` right and left margin to allow me to specify the value of `10px`. (Sorry for all the confusion and the back and forth of comments and thanks a whole lot for your time and effort!)

Comment: Oh wow, now I realize the problem is with Firefox. Your codepen works perfectly fine in Chrome, it's just it does not do so in Firefox which is in what i was viewing it. Well, my bad!

**Update**: I think I have found a more elegant solution to the problem using `calc()` to set the width. I will post it as an answer, but will accept your answer regardless, as it is a far better fit for most cases and you put all of this effort into it! Thanks a whole lot again!

Answer (score 2):

You could solve it with div parent, which uses `margin` instead of progress bar.

```css
progress {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin: 2px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0.5px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background: #eeeeee;
  color: #01579b;
}
/* Foreground - webkit browsers */
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #01579b;
  border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
}
/* Background - webkit browsers */
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: #eeeeee;
}
/* Foreground - Firefox */
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: #01579b;
  border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
}
/* Max value - webkit browsers */
progress[value="1000"]::-webkit-progress-value {
  border-radius: 1px;
}
/* Max value - Firefox */
progress[value="1000"]::-moz-progress-bar {
  border-radius: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; margin: 0px 50px;">
  <progress value="450" max="1000"></progress>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there no way to fix the element itself? I am building a UI toolkit and I would like to avoid extra `<div>` elements if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the progress bar with a div and add padding. See:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
}

progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  height: 14px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0.5px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background: #eeeeee;
  color: #01579b;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
/* Foreground - webkit browsers */
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #01579b;
  border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
}
/* Background - webkit browsers */
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: #eeeeee;
}
/* Foreground - Firefox */
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: #01579b;
  border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
}
/* Max value - webkit browsers */
progress[value="1000"]::-webkit-progress-value {
  border-radius: 1px;
}
/* Max value - Firefox */
progress[value="1000"]::-moz-progress-bar {
  border-radius: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<progress value="450" max="1000"></progress>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there no way to fix the element itself? I am building a UI toolkit and I would like to avoid extra `<div>` elements if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all the other ways to solve this, I have also found that using `calc()` can solve the problem quite easily and without changing but one line from `width: 100%;` to `width: calc(100% - 20px);` - some browser-specific prefixing might be required to cover all browsers.

To generalize this solution, replace `20px` with the sum of the values of `margin-left` and `margin-right`.

```css
progress {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 14px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin: 2px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0.5px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background: #eeeeee;
  color: #01579b;
}
/* Foreground - webkit browsers */
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #01579b;
  border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
}
/* Background - webkit browsers */
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: #eeeeee;
}
/* Foreground - Firefox */
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: #01579b;
  border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
}
/* Max value - webkit browsers */
progress[value="1000"]::-webkit-progress-value {
  border-radius: 1px;
}
/* Max value - Firefox */
progress[value="1000"]::-moz-progress-bar {
  border-radius: 1px;
}
```

```html
<progress value="450" max="1000"></progress>
```